# Is there a simple way to do XML attribute comparison using XMLBeans?

Tags: xml, comparison, xmlbeans

Supposing that one has a bean with a set of hierarchical attributes, does XMLBeans provide a way to determine whether that bean has certain values for a subset of those attributes?  The best way I could come up with to solve this issue is to create another bean with the set of attributes and values that you seek, and see if your bean contains the same attributes (and values for those attributes) as the one you set up.

For example, consider you have a list of XML people, and you want to find people with brown hair.  You could set up a bean as such:

```
<person hair="brown" />
```

and find the items in your list which essentially contain that bean as a subset.  I could do this by recursively iterating through the attribute hierarchy of the test bean (in this case, the person with brown hair), and check if each bean in the list contains that attribute, and has that value for it.  But this seems like it might be a common task, and I wanted to find out if the XMLBeans library provides this functionality already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a hierarchical attribute is, but I know that you can query the original XML using XPath:

```
//person[@hair='brown']
```

to get all person elements with a 'hair' attribute equal to 'brown'. And I think you can execute XPath expressions against the XMLBeans XMLObject (or was it XQuery?, but that would be almost the same thing), so, yes, XMLBeans kind of have that functionality already. As far as I remember, you'd get a list of XMLObjects back, but I dont know if those could be cast to their particular mapped Java classes or not. Strange beast, XMLBeans! We moved on to JAXB and have no regrets.

Comment: By "hierarchical attribute", I mean simply an attribute that has attributes.  I will see what I can do with XQuery/XPath.